# PowerShell SQL query issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, powershell, azure-powershell, powershell-remoting

I'm reading a CSV column and checking it using my SQL Server Table1 column and then updated table2 column like this but I'm not sure why it's working.

I'm getting 99 for all the rows even though my CSV column is not all empty and the value is exactly matched in table1. Any help or suggestion would be really appreciated.

```
   $CSVImport = Import-CSV $CSVFileName

    ForEach ($CSVLine in $CSVImport) {
    
        $CSVEvent = $CSVLine.Event
        $CSVName = $CSVLine.Name 

        if($CSVEvent -eq ''){
            $EventID = '99'
        }else{
            $EventID = "SELECT Convert(int,Event_Id) From Table1 WHERE Event_name = '$CSVEvent'"
            Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query $EventID
        }

        $query = "INSERT INTO Table2(Event_Id, Name) VALUES($EventID, '$CSVName');"
        Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query $query
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```bash
>  Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query $EventID
> ```

This *outputs* the result of your query instead of *capturing it in a variable*. In the absence of assigning the output to a variable, redirecting it, or sending it through the pipeline, it *prints to the display*.

I assume the intent is to store the result of the `Invoke-Sqlcmd` in variable `$EventID`, as an integer:

```bash
$EventID = Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query $EventID | ForEach-Object { $_[0] }
```

However, note that if the query returns *multiple* rows, `$EventID` will be an *array* of integers.